# How to process continuously updating file from start of fail? .

Tags: linux, tail, file-processing

1 How to process from start of a continuously updating file( 1 --> infinite) ? 
2 tail -f / tail -n10 -f solution is not correct, because  it processing the file from end or some n lines form end of file. But i need to process the file from start of file to forever(continuous).

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem;  putting more number of lines than file contains (100000 > myfile size) solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

From `tail --help`:

```
-n, --lines=K            output the last K lines, instead of the last 10;
                           or use -n +K to output starting with the Kth
```

So,

```
tail -f -n +1
```

Comment: Thank you for replay, But i need out put from the first line of the file;  Reference from start not from the end of file; say some 10 lines from start to continuous  monitoring.

Comment: That's what the `-n +1` means: start at the first line. If you were to write `-n 1` it would be 1 lines from the end. Note the `+`.

Comment: Thank you, i missed the simple thing, and wasted many days for searching.